# setOnClickListener is not showing the Toast or doing the Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

this is in Kotlin, it doesn't seem to work no matter what I try it's just a button with a click listener. Its function is to take me to another activity, I tried a toast but didn't show either. I tried not using the function and also didn't work. and can we use this method with a text view? I'm new in Kotlin so easy on me...

here's the code

```
  val startButton = binding.loginButton

startButton.setOnClickListener {
    fun crtUser() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "It's Working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, SignupActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
        crtUser()
    }
}
```

I also used finish() after the Intent, and it crashed

Comment: The inner function `crtUser` is sort of pointless here, but still valid syntax - this code works fine when I try it. If something is crashing, look in the logcat and find the stack trace. If your question is about a crash, *always* include that stack trace in the question too. Where is the code located? (inside `onCreate` in your activity?)

Comment: `class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: LoginActivityBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = LoginActivityBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)`

Comment: yes it's inside the onCreate... still not working tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use this syntax, it is not invalid, but improving it will be much better for you and for other developers to understand faster and easily what is going on :). Trigger the function from the on click event as follows:

```
fun onCreateOrOtherMethod() {
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        createUser()
    }
}
```

And then you can have createUser() as an inner method of your current class:

```
private fun createUser() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "It's Working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, SignupActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Little tip: don't abbreviate the methods names, you can use long name if needed as long as it improves the semantics of your code.

If it crashes, please, attach the Exception stack trace :D

Comment: `         fun clickListener(){

            Toast.makeText(this, "you were really High!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
             val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, SignupActivity::class.java)
             startActivity(intent)
             finish()
        }

        val loginBTNButton = binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener{
            clickListener()
        }`

Comment: Still not woking, not even showing the toast

Answer (score 0):

It's working now just after I changed this

```
setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)
```

To this

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Any Idea Why??

Comment: oh, wasn't on the question that part of the code :D, but indeed the ViewTreeOwners are not set with the binding class. Resuming it: every binding class is autogenerated by Android Studio on the background (due to viewBinding annotation), it contains your layout and the objects from your layout, so if you set a listener to one view from the binding class, that root view from that binding layout object should be set into the activity to set the ViewTreeOwners and inflate it. Hope it helps :D

Comment: This is why it's important to post the full code in the question, not just the part *you* think is relevant

Comment: it's clear now, Thanks bro.